# Django-Filebrowser cannot create a version with auto width and constrained height?

Tags: django, django-filebrowser

I've been using Django-Filebrowser and setting up my versions [as specified in the docs](http://django-filebrowser.readthedocs.org/en/latest/settings.html), which indicate you specify image versions like so:

```
VERSIONS = getattr(settings, "FILEBROWSER_VERSIONS", {
    'thumbnail': {'verbose_name': 'Thumbnail (1 col)', 'width': 60, 'height': 60, 'opts': 'crop'},
    'small': {'verbose_name': 'Small (2 col)', 'width': 140, 'height': '', 'opts': ''},
})
```

...note the 'small' version size with an unspecified height, which successfully generates an image version with a constrained width and an auto height. This works successfully for me, however the reverse does not (constrained height but auto width):

```
'auto_width': {'verbose_name': 'Auto Width', 'width': '', 'height': 140, 'opts': ''},
```

Is there a trick here that I'm missing, or does the library not have this ability?

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same issue and resolved it: https://github.com/sehmaschine/django-filebrowser/issues/278

There is a bug in the `scale_and_crop` function in `utils.py` when trying to generate versions with fixed height and automatic width (the other way around it works like a charm). The versions image will be created but with the original size.

Example VERSION definition:

```
FILEBROWSER_VERSIONS = { 
  'medium': {'verbose_name': 'Medium (4col )', 'width': '', 'height': 250, 'opts': ''},
}
```

The reason for it is that the width variable is an empty string which gets compared to a float, therefore the if statement returns False and the image won't get resized.

One way to fix it would be to convert the width string into a float for comparing in `utils.py`:

```
66c65
<     if 'upscale' not in opts and x < width:
---
>     if 'upscale' not in opts and x < float(width or 0):
```